# Irreducible Polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am interested in generating irreducible polynomials of a given, arbitrary degree over either the reals or rationals using integer coefficients. They don't necessarily have to be arbitrary polynomials (i.e. random coefficients), but I would prefer not to simply use $F(x)=x^n+a_n$ (for the case of $\mathbb{R}$.

If a general algorithm for generating arbitrary irreducible polynomials does not exist, I am open to using several "families" of polynomials of arbitrary degree which are known to be irreducible, in which case I would like to be able to generate several different such families.

Comment: There don't exist irreducible polynomials of arbitrary degree over $\mathbf{R}$: all polynomials factor into a product of linear and quadratic factors.

Comment: Irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb{R}$ are precisely the constants, the linear polynomials, and the quadratic polynomials with negative discriminant.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize that about the reals. Thanks!

Comment: You may enjoy looking into irreducible polynomials over finite fields; this is quite interesting.  For example, consider polynomials whose coefficients are in $\Bbb Z_2$, which means the field containing only $0$ and $1$, with addition and multiplication as you expect, except that $1+1=0$. There is a unique irreducible polynomial of degree 2, namely $x^2+x+1$, and of 8 possible degree-3 polynomials, exactly 2 are irreducible. There is a lot of very fascinating theory at work here, including a lovely theorem of Gauss that counts of irreducible polynomials of each order.

Comment: @MJD: I'm definitely interested in it, I'm just trying to narrow down certain results to rational (and I guess not real) polynomials for now. I plan on tackling some fun finite fields soon, too. In which case I've seen several results (such as results by Shoup) on constructing irreducibles in finite fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the rationals, use the [Eisenstein Irreducibility Criterion.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion)

Over the reals is not interesting, no polynomial of degree $\ge 3$ is irreducible.